# Unable to show data on Data Table at startsup the page while using Search filter but showing data after search something?

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

I trying to implement rows Search on Data Table on my flutter web app using TextEditingController. The data comes from The API as Json formte using Employee model.
I used FutureBuilder to get the data from the API. And i inserted Snapshot data into 'empList' as List. Also Created empsFiltered List to show search filtered data.

The issue is: Unable to show actual data in the datatable on startup. But the data is shown while searching and after clearing the searchtextfield.

I want to show the actual data on startup. And also the data should be shown as searched.

How to do this.

```
class EditorHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditorHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditorHomeState createState() => _EditorHomeState();
}

class _EditorHomeState extends State<EditorHome> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  String _searchResult = '';

  List empList = [];
  List empsFiltered = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    empsFiltered = empList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Fetch Data Table Example with search'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Card(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.search),
                title: TextField(
                    controller: searchController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Search', border: InputBorder.none),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _searchResult = value;
                        empsFiltered = empList
                            .where((e) =>
                                e.name.contains(_searchResult.toLowerCase()) ||
                                e.email.contains(_searchResult.toLowerCase()))
                            .toList();
                      });
                    }),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      searchController.clear();
                      _searchResult = '';
                      empsFiltered = empList;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FutureBuilder<List<Employees>>(
              //initialData: const <Employees>[],
              future: fetchResults(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError ||
                    snapshot.data == null ||
                    snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
                empList = snapshot.data!;

                return DataTable(
                  headingTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                  headingRowHeight: 50,
                  showBottomBorder: true,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1)),
                  columns: const [
                    DataColumn(label: SizedBox(width: 30, child: Text('ID'))),
                    DataColumn(
                        label: SizedBox(width: 100, child: Text('Name'))),
                    DataColumn(
                        label: SizedBox(width: 100, child: Text('Email'))),
                  ],
                  rows: List.generate(
                    empsFiltered.length,
                    (index) {
                      var emp = empsFiltered[index];
                      return DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(
                          Text(emp.id.toString()),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(emp.name),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                          Text(emp.email),
                        ),
                      ]);
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Below is my API:

```
Future<List<Employees>> fetchResults() async {
  //List<Employees> _results = [];
  Uri url = Uri.parse(" http:link ");
  var response = await http.get(url);
  var resultsJson = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  List<Employees> emplist = await resultsJson
      .map<Employees>((json) => Employees.fromJson(json))
      .toList();
  return emplist;
}
```

Comment: so what it shows on startup ? empty data?

Comment: yes. Shows empty data.. I think so List empsFiltered = []; is empty... on start up untill Clear the  searchController..

Comment: For example if i enter matching text on searchController. It shows the matched rows.. And  if i clear the text on it.. It shows all data rows. But not shows the data at startup until clear the searchController..

Comment: add `print(snapshot.data!.toString());` below `empList = snapshot.data!;`, see what it prints.

Comment: You should create a state variable to contain the result of fetchResults, call fetchResults/set that variable in your initState. Use that new variable as future of the futureBuilder instead of the function call directly

Comment: @CharlesRostaing Can you please give me an example.

Comment: @JohnJoe : It prints : ```[Instance of 'Employees', Instance of 'Employees', Instance of 'Employees', Instance of 'Employees']
 ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution. In this Case I used Two StatefulWidgets. One is for calling Future with fetchResults() and converted into a List, And second is for Table with Search filter, And called that first stateFulWidget List into a variable on second StatefulWidgets and set that List variable in initState as into empFiltered List. Working Fine.

Example Code:

```
class EditorHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditorHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EditorHomeState createState() => _EditorHomeState();
}

class _EditorHomeState extends State<EditorHome> {
  List empList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Employees>>(
        future: fetchResults(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError ||
              snapshot.data == null ||
              snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          empList = snapshot.data!;
          return TableSec(fempList: empList);
        });
  }
}

class TableSec extends StatefulWidget {
  final List fempList;
  const TableSec({Key? key, required this.fempList}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TableSecState createState() => _TableSecState();
}

class _TableSecState extends State<TableSec> {
  late List empList = widget.fempList;
  List empsFiltered = [];

  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  String _searchResult = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    empsFiltered = empList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Table"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Card(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.search),
                title: TextField(
                    controller: searchController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Search', border: InputBorder.none),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        _searchResult = value;
                        empsFiltered = empList
                            .where((e) =>
                                e.name.contains(_searchResult.toLowerCase()) ||
                                e.email.contains(_searchResult.toLowerCase()))
                            .toList();
                        //print(_searchResult);
                      });
                    }),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      searchController.clear();
                      _searchResult = '';
                      empsFiltered = empList;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            DataTable(

              headingTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
              headingRowHeight: 50,
              showBottomBorder: true,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1)),
              columns: const [
                DataColumn(label: SizedBox(width: 30, child: Text('ID'))),
                DataColumn(label: SizedBox(width: 100, child: Text('Name'))),
                DataColumn(label: SizedBox(width: 100, child: Text('Email'))),
              ],
              rows: List.generate(
                empsFiltered.length,
                (index) {
                  var emp = empsFiltered[index];
                  return DataRow(cells: [
                    DataCell(
                      Text(emp.id.toString()),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text(emp.name),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text(emp.email),
                    ),
                  ]);
                },
              ).toList(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting here to add the code snippet:

You should create a state variable to contain the result of fetchResults, call fetchResults/set that variable in your initState. Use that new variable as future of the futureBuilder instead of the function call directly

```
class _EditorHomeState extends State<EditorHome> {
  Future<List> futureList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureList = fetchResults();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ...
      FutureBuilder<List<Employees>>(
        future: futureList,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not accepting at ```fure:futureList,``` It is showing problem: ```The argument type 'Future<List<dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<List<Employees>>?'```